# How to delete the last two rows of a df with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rows

Here is the code I'm playing with. I want to delete the last two lines of the file. I'm actually working on a bigger file and the last two lines fluctuate. Once I get it to work on this small format, I will implement it in my primary source code.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
    'year': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014], 
    'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Cochice', 'Pima', 'Santa Cruz', 
'Maricopa', 'Yuma'])
df
df.drop(dr.index[-2])
```

This will remove the second row from the bottom but I am trying to delete to rows that will be followed by NaN

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Beter is select all rows without last 2 by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.iloc[:-2]
print (df)
             name  year  reports
Cochice     Jason  2012        4
Pima        Molly  2012       24
Santa Cruz   Tina  2013       31
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `df.tail` to achieve that too -

```
df.drop(df.tail(n).index,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try like this way to remove **last 2 rows**?

```
df = df[:-2]
```

**Output:**

After removing last 2 rows

```
            name   year  reports
Cochice     Jason  2012        4
Pima        Molly  2012       24
Santa Cruz   Tina  2013       31
```

**Working Demo:** https://repl.it/repls/UnacceptableWrithingQuotes